# BsonDocument basic math (sum) MongoDB.Driver C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

I have a collection of BsonDocuments that look like the following:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5699715218a323101c663b9a"),
        "amount" : 24.32,
        "color" : false
}
```

I would like to sum all of the values for "amount" in this particular collection (~1,000 BsonDocuments).

This is what I have so far:

```
var group = new BsonDocument{
                        { "$group", new BsonDocument
                            {
                                { "_id", "$amount" },                       
                            }
                        }
                    };

var pipeline = new[] { group };
var result = collection.Aggregate(pipeline);`
```

The last line where the variable "result" is declared gives me the error: "The type arguments for methods Aggregate cannot be inferred from the usage." I really feel like this error comes from how I set up the "group" BsonDocument but in reality I'm not sure if this is even the direction I should be going in. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

**[EDIT]** Maximilianos Rios's answer has worked. Furthermore if one would like to count the documents processed it would be done the following way:

```
var aggregation = collection.Aggregate<BsonDocument>()
        .Group(new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "_id", BsonNull.Value
                        },
                        {
                            "total_amount", new BsonDocument
                                         {
                                             {
                                                 "$sum", "$amount"
                                             }
                                         }
                        },
                        {
                            "sum", new BsonDocument
                                         {
                                             {
                                                 "$sum", 1
                                             }
                                         }
                        }

                    });

   var doc = aggregation.Single();
   BsonDocument result = doc.AsBsonDocument;
   var total = result["total_amount"].AsDouble;
   var count = result["sum"].AsInt32;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all, what you want to do based on your question is this:

```
db.coll.aggregate([ { $group: { _id:null, total_amount:{"$sum":"$amount"}} } ])
```

Quoting your words

> I would like to sum all of the values for "amount" in this particular
>   collection

The solution is to use the group method of the aggregation framework like this:

```
var aggregation = collection.Aggregate<BsonDocument>()
            .Group(new BsonDocument 
                        { 
                            { "_id", BsonNull.Value
                            }, 
                            { 
                                "total_amount", new BsonDocument 
                                             { 
                                                 { 
                                                     "$sum", "$amount" 
                                                 } 
                                             } 
                            } 
                        });

            var doc = aggregation.Single();
            BsonDocument result = doc.AsBsonDocument;
            var total = result["total_amount"].AsDouble;
```

Remember you can get your value asynchronously too.

```
var doc = aggregation.SingleAsync();
```

Comment: This worked absolutely perfect. If I wanted to add a new field "document_amount" next to total amount that simply counted documents using "$sum" ,1 how would I insert this? Thanks so much

Comment: Do you want to count the documents? You can count without using a new field. I'm going to write below the MongoDb query.

Comment: db.sumtable.aggregate([ { $group: { _id:null, total_amount:{"$sum":"$amount"}, total_documents:{$sum:1}} } ])

Comment: Awsome. Thanks for your help Maximiliano. It worked exactly as it should!